# How can i detect the change in network state and reload my android app if the connectivity is available

Tags: android, webview, wifi

I have an android app which runs when internet connection is active. When the connection is not available, a dialog box appears through which wifi can be activated. I have made the app to quit when connection is not available after initiating wifi connection. The question is, i have to reload the app and continue using the app when the internet connection is available after enabling the wifi rather than to exit the app.

Here is the code:

```
if (CheckConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
        //load a webview and show contents from web.
   }

        else
        {
        try {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this).create();

    alertDialog.setTitle("Info");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Internet Connection not available. Please cross check your internet connectivity and try again.");
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.error);
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);



    alertDialog.setButton2("WiFi Setting", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings");
            startActivity(intent);
            System.exit(0);

        }
     });

    alertDialog.show();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question needs more detail as your audience doesn't know what you mean by 'reload my android app' and 'quit' in the context of Android's activity lifecycle. It may help to include parts of your code which describes what you are doing along with a description. Also there are also lots of answers on SO about Android and network state so it may help to look.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call System.exit(0).

First of all because it is not a recommended way of quitting your app and makes it look to the user as if it crashed.

Second, why are you exiting at all? The user will be navigated to the internet settings, switch them on and when they press back, your activity will already be there. You can recheck internet status onResume of your activity. This is the acceptable way of handling an unavailable internet connection in your application.

Comment: yes i want to implement the same technique. can you please help with some pseudocode and can i use onResume within the dialog box.

Comment: That's exactly what i did in my answer. Remove the System.exit(0) line. And call your network check in the onResume function.